# System.err vs System.out

Tags: java, xml

What is difference between

```
System.out.println("Programming");
```

and

```
System.err.println("Programming");
```

when both `err` and `out` are the object of `Printstream` class?

Comment: You may read about stout and stderr as background why this two streams exist - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams or other similar sources...

Answer (score 3):

These are different [data streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). One is the so-called *standard output stream* (STDOUT), the other is the *standard error stream* (STDERR).

Answer (score 1):

yes you are right by default both stream flushing the output in console but you can reassign this two stream to different channel. Like -

```
System.setOut(new FileInputStream("outputfile.txt"));
System.setErr(new FileInputStream("errfile.txt"));
```

and try this -

```
try{
   System.out.println("Try");
   int i =1/0;
}catch(Exception ex){
   System.err.println(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter t error and regular messages through the console. It's useful when you have few of one diluted in thousands of others.